# Refresh class with an onPressed Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I have an onPressed which translate my context in a class and I want to refresh an another class when I push the button OnPressed. I start to add the class in the onPress :

```
class ClassA {
onPressed: () {
    changeLocale(context, 'en');
   _ClassB();
 },
}

    class ClassB extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ClassBState createState() => _ClassBState();
}

class _ClassBState extends State<ClassB> {
...
}
```

How I can refresh the _classB with onPressed ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need some variant of the observer design pattern. Post a small but complete example app. All code in main.dart.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using state management for such scenarios 
Like provider, scopedmodel , bloc pattern

Comment: In fact I tried it but the class isn't refresh... In fact I have a listview and I want to select one item of this list view...

Answer (score 1):

```
onPressed: () {
    changeLocale(context, 'en');
   _ClassB();
   setState(() {});
 },
}
```

doesn't work?

Comment: No, the class doesn't restart , I have a void initState in the class B but when I call it in the Class A by classB().initState, nothing happen